# Do we have $[H_1H_2:H_1]=[H_2:H_1\cap H_2]$?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $H_1,H_2$ be finite field extensions over $\Bbb{Q}$. Suppose $H_1\cap H_2=\Bbb{Q}$, Do we have:
$$ [H_1H_2:\Bbb{Q}]=[H_1:\Bbb{Q}]\cdot [H_2:\Bbb{Q}]$$

I know it is true for Galois extension. But it is true for finite extensions?

THANKS!